# jquery inputmask with empty value submits 0.00 instead of empty string

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I am using jquery inputmask with with the latest version, downloaded today (v. 3.1.64-86).

I have a simple "OvertimeFee" text input and have setup the mask on it with the code below.

```
$('#OvertimeFee').inputmask('currency', {
    'autoUnmask': true,
    'removeMaskOnSubmit': true,
    'clearMaskOnLostFocus': true,
    'clearIncomplete': true,
    'prefix': '',
    'rightAlign': false,
    'showMaskOnHover': false
});
```

No initial value is bound to it when the page is loaded, and user's are not required to fill the field when submitting the form

The problem I am having is that whenever the user leaves the field blank or enters a value and then removes it, the form always submits "0.00" instead of an empty value ("").  I would like the form to always submit "" if the user didn't populate it, but I can't figure out how to make inputmask do that.  Even with autoUnmask and removeMaskOnSubmit set to true it still submits "0.00".

Does anyone know how to pull this off?  I've had no luck searching the github issues.

Thanks.

FWIW, the scripts included and being used on the page are:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/inputmask.numeric.extensions.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

After encountering this issue myself, I see two viable solutions.

The first is to write server-side logic to intercept "0.00" values sent by forms and convert them to empty string values. This solution maintains data integrity but may require long hours of coding if jquery-inputmask is used many times across a large site.

The second is to revert to an earlier jquery-inputmask version, such as 3.1.64. I chose this solution since my site does not require any of the changes introduced in 3.1.64-86.